# Compress Newline character for dynamic varaibles

Tags: sas, sas-macro

```
Dataset: Have
F1      F2

Student Section
Name    No
```

Dataset "Have". Data has new line character.

I need to compress the newline character from the data.

I want to do this dynamically as sometimes the "Have" dataset may contain new variables like `F3,F4,F5 etc.`,

I have written as macro to do this.. However it is not working as expected.

When i execute the below code, first time I am getting error as invalid reference newcnt. If i execute for second time in the same session, i am not getting error.

PFB my code:

```
%macro update_2(newcnt);

data HAVE;
    set HAVE;
    %do i= 1 %to &newcnt;
        %let colname = F&i;
        &colname=compress(&colname,,'c');
    %end;
run;

%mend update_2;


%macro update_1();

proc sql noprint;
    select count(*) into :cnt from dictionary.columns where libname="WORK" and memname="HAVE"; 
quit;

%update_2(&cnt)

%mend update_1;
```

Note: All the variables have name as `F1,F2,F3,F4.`,

Please tell me what is going wrong..

If there is any other procedures, please help me.

Comment: I agree with Haikuo's non-macro solution.  But I tried your code as is, and it executed as you expect.  If you stick with the macro approach, I would suggest declaring macro variables CNT, I, and COLNAME to be %local to their respective macros, to avoid collisions with any other existing macro vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We created our own function to clean unwanted characters from strings using `proc fcmp`.  In this case, our function cleans tab characters, line feeds, and carriage returns.

```
proc fcmp outlib=common.funcs.funcs; /* REPLACE TARGET DESTINATION AS NECESSARY */

  function clean(iField $) $200;    
    length cleaned $200;
    bad_char_list = byte(10) || byte(9) || byte(13);  
    cleaned = translate(iField," ",bad_char_list);
    return (cleaned );
  endsub;

run;
```

Create some test data with a new line character in the middle of it, then export it and view the results.  You can see the string has been split across lines:

```
data x;
  length employer $200;
  employer = cats("blah",byte(10),"diblah"); 
run;

proc export data=x outfile="%sysfunc(pathname(work))\x.csv" dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

Run our newly created `clean()` function against the string and export it again.  You can see it is now on a single line as desired:

```
data y;
  set x;
  employer = clean(employer);
run;

proc export data=y outfile="%sysfunc(pathname(work))\y.csv" dbms=csv replace;
run;
```

Now to apply this method to all character variables in our desired dataset.  No need for macros, just define an array referencing all the character variables, and iterate over them applying the `clean()` function as we go:

```
data cleaned;
  set x;
  array a[*] _char_;
  do cnt=lbound(a) to hbound(a);
    a[cnt] = clean(a[cnt]);
  end;
run;
```

**EDIT** : Also note that fcmp may have some performance considerations to consider.  If you are working with very large amounts of data, there may be other solutions that will perform better.

**EDIT 6/15/2020** : Corrected missing length statement that could result in truncated responses.

Comment: @Joe Typical of me not to read the full question =)... I will update my answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Fixed.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'll reiterate my note about FCMP having poor performance, so keep that in mind if used on a large dataset.  What I'd think the FCMP might be more helpful for honestly (other than code hiding, which is a benefit of course) is if you let it take an array and the function cleans the whole array.  Only in later version of SAS (maybe 9.4+ even) is this allowed but it would be very handy.

Comment: @Joe As I was editing the answer I was just wondering if fcmp would allow for the `of` syntax like some of the numeric functions have, eg. `x = sum(of _numeric_)`.  Passing arrays to FCMP would also be a very nice feature. Oh, and I believe 'code hiding' is more commonly referred to as 'code-reuse' ;-)

Comment: @Joe Thinking about this a little more, I can see why this would be considered 'code hiding'.  Yes, there are simple one line commands that perform the functionality encapsulated in this fcmp function.  And typically one-liners don't deserve wrappers because they are so simple.  I consider this case slightly different because it's a 'rare' issue (at least in the domain I work in). So when it comes up, I can never remember how (or where) I fixed it last time.  I can however remember if I've created a macro or a function to deal with it, so that's why IMO it deserved it's own FCMP.

Answer (score 3):

In your macro `%update_1` you're creating a macro variable called `&cnt`, but when you call `%update_2` you refer to another macro variable, `&colcnt`. Try fixing this reference and see if your code behaves as expected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks!. I updated my question. It is a typo error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of Robert Penridge's function, as a call routine with an array as an argument.  This probably only works in 9.4+ or possibly later updates of 9.3, when permanent arrays began being allowed to be used as arguments in this way.

I'm not sure if this could be done flexibly with an array as a function; without using macros (which require recompilation of the function constantly) I don't know how one could make the right size of array be returned without doing it as a call routine.

I added 'Z' to the drop list so it's obvious that it works.

```
options cmplib=work.funcs;

proc fcmp outlib=work.funcs.funcs;
  sub clean(iField[*] $);  
    outargs iField; 
    bad_char_list = byte(11)|| byte(10) || byte(9) || byte(13)||"Z";  
    do _i = 1 to dim(iField);
      iField[_i] = translate(iField[_i],trimn(" "),bad_char_list);
    end;
  endsub;
quit;


data y;
  length employer1-employer5 $20;
  array employer[4] $; 
  do _i = 1 to dim(employer);
    employer[_i] = "Hello"||byte(32)||"Z"||"Goodbye";
  end;
  employer5 = "Hello"||byte(32)||"Z"||"Goodbye";
  call clean(employer);
run;

proc print data=y;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative. If newline is the only thing you want to remove, then we are talking about Char only, you may leverage implicit array and Do over,

```
data want;
set have;
array chr _character_;
do over chr;
chr=compress(chr,,'c');
end;
run;
```

Comment: `do over` is deprecated and should be instead used with an iterator, `do _i = 1 to dim(chr); ... `

Comment: I would call it 'unadvertised'. Besides, I think SAS really like the concept that they have implemented another do-over on Hash from 9.4, and we all know Hash used to be called 'associated array'.

Comment: It was removed from the documentation, so it would be "Deprecated", not "undocumented".  Either way, it is not something that is guaranteed to work in future releases (similar to `monotonic`, though that was actually never documented if I recall correctly) and shouldn't be suggested in answers in my opinion if there is a simple way to do it without using that functionality.

Comment: If SAS wants it to be 'deprecited', it would have done something like this:http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/whatsdiff/63859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1jzdl568l3vgln1bymihcpsi6ry.htm . So that this moment, it is just matter of opinion.

Comment: SAS removed do over well before it did things like issue deprecated lists (that are findable now, anyway).  It wasn't in v8 documentation, at a minimum (and that's as far back as I can find decent online documentation).  Regardless, it's irresponsible to use an undocumented OR deprecated function without noting that it is such, and in particular when there is a perfectly good alternative with no performance hit or significant increase in code.

Comment: Not to turn into an etymology debate, but this prompted me to read Wikipedia on "deprecated."  I think from SAS Inst point of view, do over is deprecated because it was once documented and now removed. That said, there are notables (Dorfman) who still advocate for its use.  It is not likely to be removed (IMHO).  Some deprecated procs have even returned (e.g. PROC DELETE). But agree, it's worth noting in answers when a deprecated or undocumented feature is used, to avoid readers being confused.

Comment: Well, they could always add it in, and they didn't. Like I said, and many of programmer would have agreed, at this moment, it is a matter of different opinions. You voiced yours, and I voiced mine. Let's call it a day.

Comment: I have no problem using the function if you like.  I just want you to put something in the answer noting that it is undocumented, so users aren't surprised.  That's common courtesy (and has nothing to do with opinion).